# Rules Looping for Multiple User References

Tags: 6, entities, rules, users

I have a Rule which checks to see if a "Reviewer" CCK User reference field has been changed. If it has been, it loads the referenced user and add the "Reviewer" role. This works perfectly however it only works for the first value in the field, so adding multiple reviewers becomes a problem.

I can see in the "load a referenced user" action that is says "Note that if the field has multiple values, only the first user will be loaded." So I assume this has come up before...

Is there any way around this for Rules 1.x on Drupal 6? I need to Loop this for each set value in the field array but I cant find the best way to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write you're own condition. See http://drupal.org/node/298486.

Comment: Looks good, I was wondering how I can make an argument available to the "add role" action - as it seems the problem is really that "load referenced user" only loads the first value. 

Do you know where I implement "hook_rules_condition_info()" does this need to be in a custom module or can I use it in "execute PHP action"?

Also how can I find out if the "add role" action will accept an array and what structure it requires?

Comment: That has to go to a custom module. In general: Find a module which provides an action the way you want it and learn from their source.